# Почему разный результат выполнения в PyCharm и командной строке

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Почему разный результат выполнения в PyCharm и командной строке, см скрин[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, не используйте изображения для текста. Просто вставляйте текст в пост

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, нужно вначале сказать несколько слов об операторе `is`.

> The operator `is` test for object identity: `x is y` is `true` if and only if `x` and `y` are the same object.

Перевод:

> Оператор `is` проверяет идентичность объектов: `x is y` истинно тогда и только тогда, когда `x` и `y` являются одним и тем же объектом.

В консоли `Python` выполним следующее:

```
>>> a = "many paths"
>>> b = "many paths"
>>> a is b
False
>>> hex(id(a))
'0x6327f0'
>>> hex(id(b))
'0x632930'
```

Здесь видно, что переменные `a` и `b` расположены в разных областях памяти, т.е. являются *разными объектами с идентичным содержимым*. Именно поэтому оператор `is` возвращает `False`.

Теперь выполним следующую программу:

```
a = "many paths"
b = "many paths"
print(a is b)
print(hex(id(a)), hex(id(b)))
```

Результат выполнения:

```
True
0x632840 0x632840
```

Здесь обе переменные ссылаются на один и тот же адрес, поэтому оператор `is` возвращает `True`.

Различное поведение связано с различиями работы Python'а в режиме консоли (выполнение команд по мере ввода пользователем) и в режиме выполнения уже написанной программы. В режиме выполнения программы включается оптимизатор памяти, в то время как в режиме консоли он выключен. Поскольку готовая программа Python'ом компилируется в промежуточный байт-код, у него есть возможность проанализировать все использования переменных и оптимизировать их размещение. В режиме консоли дальнейшие действия неизвестны и интерпретатор, скорее всего, просто "перестраховывается", отключая эту оптимизацию.

P.S. Описанное в вопросе поведение возникает не только в PyCharm, а при выполнении программы независимо от среды.

Comment: На самом деле в консоли тоже можно получить `true`. Если взять короткую строку (например "c"), скорее всего Питон даст True на `a is b`. У меня вообще получилось добиться (в консоли!) `False` только при строке длиной около 50 символов. Скажем для строки "hdgfsjshgfjshdgfjasdhgfjasdghfasjhdfgdjashgf" у меня получается `True`. А в целом, ответ, конечно, верный.

Comment: @andy.37 Python 3.5.0 win32. Даёт `False` даже на односимвольных строках, но `True` на пустых и очень длинных. Видимо, результат зависит от версии.

Comment: а может и от ОС. Я на python2.7/python3.4.3 Ubuntu смотрел